# Panasonic PhotoMOS Relay with AC Load

Tags: ac, solid-state-relay

I’m looking at the Panasonic 600V 40mA relay AQW216A (https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic-Industrial-Devices/AQW216A?qs=QVBMgXxBiLwcjOQSSsoh0w%3D%3D) for a dual Voltmeter/Ohmmeter circuit. When the relay is open, it will experience AC voltages in the range of 120-347Vrms.

On the surface this relay looks like a good fit because it can handle up to 600Vpk. My question here is: should there be a larger cushion between my Vpk (~490V) and the rated maximum? This circuit will be protected with bidirectional TVS diodes so I hope to quickly snuff all overshoots, but am still unsure if I need a larger difference between my Vmax and the spec. (Like if I need to use a 1kVpk, or 1.5kVpk relay instead)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *it will experience AC voltages in the range of 120-347Vrms*

If you are using this device to connect to regular AC mains power circuits then the upstream indirect-lightning protection circuits in most building will limit the peak voltage to around 1500 volts with respect to earth. If you are using this beyond the home or office then it could be over 2000 volts to earth and sometimes may even be as high as 6000 volts on unprotected circuits.

In any of the above scenarios, the device is going to fail miserably I suspect.

> *This circuit will be protected with bidirectional TVS diodes.*

I'm wondering how this is going to work because you don't usually find TVS diodes rated greater than 500 volts and this is far too close to the peak of 490 volts implied by 347 volts RMS. Even if you were able to find a 550 volt rated TVS then, how will that TVS be protected against the peaks of around 1500 volts you will see in lightning protection zones 2 and 3? A TVS is really just a zener with the capability of taking a very short-in-time high current surge and, to get one to handle peak currents of a hundreds of amps (as implied by the surge protection used in LPZ 2/3) is going to be really difficult.

The easiest way to do this is choose a device that can survive in the appropriate LPZ: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.lsp-international.com/surge-protection-device-spd/)

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful! 90% of the time this product will be used on an assembly line with a programmable AC Power Source (FC205 From Adaptive Power). In this situation it is reasonable to assume those high-voltage spikes won't arise, since the output AC Voltage is 'conditioned' in a sense?

Comment: Also: when this device is plugged into a generic AC outlet instead of a conditioned programmable source (10% of the time), will adding 'lightning protection circuitry' between the device and the wall outlet rule out seeing these high-voltage spikes?

Comment: And lastly: do you know how benchtop DMMs that are made to measure 0-1kVpk handle this issue (such as the Keysight 34461A, but really any standard benchtop meter)?

Comment: 1) yes I guess that should be ok. 2) no, I don’t think so. 3) resistor dividers are the answer rather than using the photo relays directly connected to the sharp and nasty end of the AC line.

Comment: Makes sense. Problem with my application is I need the SSR connected directly to the load to measure resistance before the AC Voltage is applied (is like a wiring + light-up test). I realize this is a tangent topic now, but how do any small/commonplace/cheap AC devices (smart outlets, iPhone chargers, etc...) handle these types of spikes?

Comment: They might use triacs but, without schematic details I don't really know @cdubs

Comment: Ok. I should've provided more details: for my circuit I have 800Vpk, off-state triacs placed before the 600V SSR. Triac is set to 'open' when the SSR closes to measure resistance. Then the configuration flips (triac closes, SSR opens) to allow the load to be energized.

Comment: Schematic please and a proper detailed one. The devil will be in the detail and not in the words. But, I'm not that inclined to be involved with an evolving question so maybe make a new one @cdubs.